# How to copy a row from a sheet and paste multiple versions with minor changes to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a unique situation. I am creating a low-tech work management system. I have a sheet "Work Orders" in which each row after the header contains a work order. However, work orders can be several days long. So, I need a separate sheet that shows each daily task per work order. So, for example, if a work order is from 1/12/17 to 1/14/17 I want to automate the creation of three rows in another sheet to represent each day. The purpose is to be able to assign crews based on each daily task.

This is what I wrote so far, but admit I am not sure where the error(s) are or if I'm even close. I'm an amateur for sure.

In this example the "Word Orders" sheet is my source sheet, "Schedule" is my target sheet, AD and AE are the columns with the start and end date, and AI is my conditional, IF "Yes" for the onEdit.

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Work Orders");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var startdate = source_sheet.getRange("AD"+(source_range));
  var enddate = source_sheet.getRange("AE"+(source_range));
  var duration = enddate - startdate + 1
  var event = (source_sheet.getRange("AI"+(source_range));
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":AJ"+(last_row+1));

  if (source_sheet.getRange("AI"+(source_range)) == "Yes");
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  }
```

I don't need this to be an onEdit() trigger either. I do have a custom menu item that I could use instead. I wouldn't need the conditional "Yes" in AI anylonger if I use this option.

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Triggers')
      .addItem('Create Daily Task', 'CreateDailyTask')
      .addToUi();
};
```

1st Edit:

Finally, if there is a way to have the date's change per pasted row to indicate that each is distinct, that would be the icing on the cake.

2nd Edit:

I'll also mention, though unaware if it matters, that my origin sheet "Work orders" has a script that sorts it automatically:

```
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 30th column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName("Work Orders");
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 30;
  var tableRange = "A2:AJ"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you run this in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has errors and is missing the getValue methods needed.  Here is a quick tweak to get you started:

```
function CreateDailyTask() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Work Orders");
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  var source_row = source_range.getRow();
  var source_data = source_range.getValues();
  var startdate = source_sheet.getRange("AD"+(source_row)).getValue();
  var enddate = source_sheet.getRange("AE"+(source_row)).getValue();
  var duration = enddate - startdate + 1
  var event = (source_sheet.getRange("AI"+(source_row)).getValue());
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":AJ"+(last_row+1));
  Logger.log(startdate+' '+enddate+' '+duration+' '+event); //use Logger to help you debug, this one puts the variables into the Logs (from View menu)

  if (source_sheet.getRange("AI"+(source_row)).getValue() == "Yes") {
    target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
    source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  }
}
```

Note - in order for this to work, you have to have the entire row of data selected in the Work Orders sheet. That looks like your intended workflow based on your code, though, I'm not sure if that's really the intent.